# Getting the lists of albums and its videos with Vimeo API is not working as expected

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I tried using the php library to retrieve group albums from my Vimeo account but its not giving me the data i want.

I want to be able to retrieve group, then albums relating to that group, then the videos on that album. So far, I am able to get group, but the group didn't return it albums, and trying to get albums individually with their ID is giving me the following error: The requested album couldn't be found.

Going through the developer portal

```
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/groups#get_group

group_id = 614274

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/albums#get_album
album_id = 22263
user_id = 102934564
```

I expect that the API used pull out groups with all its related albums, and through the albums i can further query to get the videos an album contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group Albums (essentially an Album within a Group) is an old Vimeo feature that isn't really supported anymore, and there are no API endpoints for interacting with them. Depending on your usecase, you may want to consider using Showcases (for sharing your content externally) or Projects (for collaboration within a team). These features have API endpoints that are readily supported, see the documentation here:

Showcases: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/228908367-Showcases

Showcases API (note that the API still references the feature with the original name, "albums"): https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/albums

Projects: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011969887-Projects

Projects API (note that the API contains references to the feature's original name "folders", but the "projects" path is supported and should be used going forward): https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/projects

Comment: I will go with your answer because I have found out that albums in groups can not be retrieved using the current API. Although, I ended up using channels.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my token was `public` scope only.
I generated a new token with `public, private` scopes - and it worked.